# Уставы российских федераций

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика, множественное-число

Есть Российская федерация прыжков в воду, а также — баскетбола и стрельбы из лука. Российских федераций, наряду с всероссийскими, множество, и не только спортивных. Сборник их уставов можно ли назвать: «Уставы российских федераций»?

Answer (score 2):

Такое название (из-за очевидного созвучия с названием государства) может у одних вызвать недоумение (не ошибка ли?), у других - вопрос, зачем автор так иронично назвал сборник серьёзных документов. Лучше добавить слово:

> "Уставы российских *спортивных* (и таких-то ещё) федераций".